# Total.js async queries

Tags: mysql, node.js, асинхронность

Я написал Total.js проект.
При обращение от контроллера к модели, он пустое ответ дает.
Вот код модела.

```
exports.getTarifs = function(f) {
    // definitions/mysql.js
    // create a DB connection
    var tarifs = [];
    // waiting for wait('waiting')
        DATABASE(function (err, connection) {
            if (err != null) {
                return;
            }

            var sql ='SELECT * FROM  `tarifs` WHERE  `f_id` = {0}'.format(f);
            connection.query(sql, function (err, rows,c) {
                // Close connection
                connection.release();
                if (err != null) {
                    return;
                }
                // Shows the result on a console window
                tarifs.push(rows);
            });
        });
     return tarifs;
};
```

Это код написано на контроллере

```
var tarifs = Tarifs.getTarifs(self.config.f);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема вот в этой строчке: `return tarifs;` То есть проблема - вообще в самом факте того, что вы пытаетесь что-то вернуть из асинхронного запроса.

Асинхронность - она заражает код. Асинхронный обработчик не может использоваться синхронным образом - любой код, использующий асинхронную обработку, сам должен стать асинхронным.

Вам следует сделать функцию `getTarifs` асинхронной - к примеру, добавить к ней callback. Как-то так:

```
exports.getTarifs = function(f, callback) {
    DATABASE(function (err, connection) {
        if (err != null) {
            callback(err);
            return;
        }

        var sql ='SELECT * FROM  `tarifs` WHERE  `f_id` = {0}'.format(f);
        connection.query(sql, function (err, rows, c) {
            // Close connection
            connection.release();
            callback(err, rows);
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.   Но так тоже не работает.    Вызов функции   `var Tarifs = MODEL('Tarifs');
console.log(Tarifs.getTarifs(0)); `  он дает `undefined`

Comment: Разумеется. Прочитайте еще раз что я написал: асинхронность заражает весь код. Если функция getTarifs стала асинхронной - то и вызывать ее надо асинхронно.